# NSIS basics go wrong

Tags: nsis

So this is a really basic question, but I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

So I am fiddling with defines in NSIS and it did not work as I would expect so I have scaled down the problem to its smallest part and I still can not make it work as I would expect.

Script looks as follows:

```
!ifndef b
!define b ""
!endif

!if $b=="b"
!define a "b"
!else
!define a "c"
!endif

Section
    MessageBox MB_OK "a: ${a} b: ${b}"
SectionEnd
```

I run it with the flag `/Db=b`.

The output is still:

```
a: "c" b: "b"
```

I am missing something trivial here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b is a define, not a variable:

```
!ifndef b
!define b ""
!endif

!if "${b}" == "b"    # <-- Modify this line.
!define a "b"
!else
!define a "c"
!endif

Section
    MessageBox MB_OK "a: ${a} b: ${b}"
SectionEnd
```

Also, I recommend you quote everything when using `if` because it'll give an error if define (or value of variable) is empty.

Comment: Thx! But it was not only the brackets that was needed. It was also the spaces around == . That is why I didn't find it a first. Because I am sure I did try bracket before posting.